# How to send values from Form to Server (Sitefinity MVC Widgets)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, sitefinity

I Want to send values from a Form to the Server.

The Form is composed by partialviews that only have inputs.
the goal of this is achieve more code reusability.
at the moment the partial views are not strongly typed but they will be.

**Submit BeginFormSitefinity**

I tried submiting the beginFormSitefinity but the widget disappears from the screen and a postback happens. However, I only want to save changes and stay in the same page. So submitting Html.BeginFormSitefinity is not an option.

**Serializing The Target Form With JQuery**

I then tried to use Jquery to send the form values.
I serialized the form by id but  I was always getting an empty result.

```
var frm = $('#AccountForm');
var jsonFrm = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()); // result = []
```

**Serializing Form Element in the Page with JQuery**

So I tried query for the "form" element in my page, as Sitefinity converts your beginformSitefinity in a DIV and adds it to a form on the fly [Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370564/beginformsitefinity-form-disappears-after-submitting).

```
var frm = $('form');
var jsonFrm = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

For my Surprise I was able to get all the values of my form and more. I also got

- "ScriptManager1_TSM"
- "ctl11_TSSM"
- "__EVENTTARGET"
- "__EVENTARGUMENT"
- "__VIEWSTATE"
- "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"
- "ctl00$ScriptManager1"

In other words this is the aspnetForm, the unique form in the page (Just Found out). 
This is not exactly what I want as it retrieves additional fields. and if I have more forms in the screen they will be retrieved too. I would prefer to get only my form's inputs as it would relief me from filtering aspnetForm.

**Questions**

Do you guys know anyway of sending only my forms value rather than sending all values from the whole aspnetForm to server?

What is the best way of sending Values of a formulary that is composed by partialviews to the server?

**Jquery**

```
 $('#btnsubmit').on('click', function () {
        var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("ControllersRoute", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" })';
        var frm = $("form").serializeArray();
        alert(frm)
        $.ajax({
            url:  url,
            type: "Post",
            data: { model: JSON.stringify(frm) },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('error');
            }

        })

    });
```

**View**

```
   @using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("Action", "AccountForm"))
    {


        Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerInfo");
        Html.RenderPartial("_DeliveryDetail");
        Html.RenderPartial("_OrderDetail");
        <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Save changes">
    }
```

**Partial Views**

_OrderDetail

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="OrderDetail" name="OrderDetail" type="text" value="Order" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

_DeliveryDetail

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="deliveryDetail" name="deliveryDetail" type="text" value="Delivery" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

_CustomerInfo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="CustomerDetail" name="CustomerDetail" type="text" value="Customer" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add a class like `send-to-server-fields` to your input fields that you want to send to server and then use `var frm = $(".send-to-server-fields").serializeArray();`

Comment: this is a nice solution and solve the filtering problem @Dandy the problem is that if i have two forms in the page I cannot distinguish which one to send. (I cannot put a diferent class to each form in the page, for design purposes)

Comment: Why do the partial views have the full Dom? HTML etc? They should only include the Dom elements you need. Not the full HTML markup. Also from your partials depending on your model which isn't posted that is see MVC looks to the name to match the Model, but you don't have any model declaration in your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want is to serialize the form and do an asynchronous POST to the server.

I'm not familiar with how you're serializing your form but this is how I do it in my Sitefinity project using jquery:

```
var $form = $('#idOfMyDivContainingMyInputs');
var serializedData = $form.find('input, select, textarea').serialize();
```

I then send this data using $.post.

Note that you cannot do this:

```
$form.serialize()
```

because jquery's serialize only works on form elements and your "form" is a div.

Comment: Yo Bochu!!!!!! This is a old post, but fortunatly I found a solution to the problem. I forgot to update the post though! The way I do at the moment  is very similar to that one you expose.

I Serialize to Array and then I stringfy in the Ajax Post!

I would love to have your contact so that we can exchange Ideas about the technology. Let me know what you think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Html.BeginFormSitefinity() instead of the default MVC

Comment: Hi Jon! But that forces the page to refresh and I dont want that

Answer (score 0):

The best method (and most MVC-friendly) method of handling this would be to use a Model. (You can also simply add a hidden field and access that after the form is posted as well).

This will allow you to display and store an item within your form for each of the properties of your Model and then easily retrieve them when the Model is posted to the server (when the form is submitted). Check out the following example for a brief walkthrough :

#### Your Model

For example purposes, I created a very basic model that houses two properties. These properties will be present within your Form so that their values can be serialized and mapped to your model for access within your Controller.

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    //Your Properties Here
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

#### Your Controller

There are two actions present, the first is simply just going to instantiate a new ExampleModel to populate your View. The second (decorated with the [HttpPost] attribute) will handle accessing the properties that were returned from your POST event.

```
//This initially renders your View
public ActionResult CreateExample()
{
     ExampleModel model = new ExampleModel();
     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
//This is for your POST event to submit your Form data to the server
public ActionResult CreateExample(ExampleModel model)
{
          //Access Properties Here using model.PropertyName
          return View(model);
}
```

#### Your View

The following View was automatically created through Visual Studio's friendly scaffolding, so there is a good deal of "fluff" here that you likely don't really need. But this will create the approprate fields for each of your properties so that they can easily be mapped to your Model.

```
@model YourProject.Models.ExampleModel

<!-- This is going to POST the Model to your CreateExample Action (Default FormMethod is a POST) -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExample","Default")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ExampleModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyOne)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyOne)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyOne)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyTwo)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyTwo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyTwo)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
<!-- enter code here -->
</fieldset>
```

}

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the answer but maybe I was not clear. In Sitefinity I'm Having troubles submiting  the Model. so I'm serializing the whole form and send it to server. I would like to know if there is a better way to do this or fix something that i'm not doing well

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked on Sitefinity I have just provided you the alternate.